# assemble is not showing the text in json file

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I am using assemble task in grunt to generate html page using handlebars like below:

```
   assemble: {
        options: {
            flatten: true,
            assets: '<%= config.tmp %>/assets',
            layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
            partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/*.hbs'
        },

        en: {
            options: {
                data: '<%= config.src %>/data/en/data.json'
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/',
                    src: '**/*.hbs',
                    dest: '<%= config.tmp %>/en_global/'
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

And I am referring the data by `{{data.title}}` in my partial files. However, in the generated html files, there is no text at all, it seems the data.json file in not loaded correctly. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you show an example of your partial? As it could be something in there rather than the config.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using `{{data.data.title}}` and see if that fixes it.